# shortcut for accessing tab menu in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When using ALT+SPACE_BAR the window menu of Google Chrome pops. but I was wondering if the same can be don for showing a tab's menu with Reload, Duplicate, New Tab, Pin Tab, etc. 
Is there a shortcut for this?

Comment: Does Alt+spacebar work for mac? I'd think it's a Windows thing (it works for all Windows) and that it's not chrome specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one for the menu I believe, however there are shortcuts for some of the separate actions though.

I suggest you look here:
http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650

Comment: The "Chrome keyboard shortcuts" you linked to don't include a shortcut for the tab menu.

Comment: This is no longer true! Which is good :) ... see the other answers. 
(maybe delete the answer? ... it's more of a comment now :) )

Comment: @noelicus Unfortunately, accepted answers cannot be deleted, even by the author. Feel free to suggest an edit to amend my answer to include that this is no longer true. :)

Answer (score 8):

On Windows and (most) Linux distros, you can use a [built-in Chrome shortcut](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650):

1. <kbd>F6</kbd> once to set focus to the omnibar
2. <kbd>F6</kbd> and again to set focus to the tab<sup>*</sup>
3. (*optionally* <kbd>Fn</kbd>+) <kbd>≡</kbd> to open the tab context menu, assuming your keyboard has a key for it

<sup>*</sup> The docs describe the shortcut as:

> Switch focus to unfocused dialog (if showing) and all toolbars

which suggests you might need to click a couple of times if another browser dialog is open - *for instance the camera or notification permission*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You can use <shift><F10> for the last step on linux.

Answer (score 6):

`Shift + F6 + (release F6 while still holding Shift) F10`

Comment: Thank you!  This is quite helpful

Answer (score 3):

Hitting F6 twice worked for me.  I used this to then access the tab's right click menu (Shift+F10) to be able to access the new tab grouping features in Chrome entirely through keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You are a keyboard god, thank you.  Reaching for the mouse is for suckers.  :-)

For me, it's: F6 > F6 > dropdown-key (dedicated key on my ergo keyboard, equiv to Shift+F10)

Comment: In Edge it seems I just have to press F6 once. Pressing twice focuses the omnibar (same as CTRL+L)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AutoHotkey script for it. It binds <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to the active tab's context menu.

Replace `0xffffff` with your Chrome theme's active tab color if it isn't white.

```autohotkey
#If WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe")

#F10::
    WinGetPos, ChromeX, ChromeY, ChromeWidth, ChromeHeight, A
    PixelSearch, ActiveTabX, ActiveTabY, 0, 0, %ChromeWidth%, %ChromeHeight%, 0xffffff, 0, Fast RGB
    
    if (ErrorLevel = 0)
    {
        Click, %ActiveTabX%, %ActiveTabY%, Right
    }
    
    Return

#If
```