# What is the Google Chrome keyboard shortcut to pin/unpin a tab?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I searched for a keyboard shortcut to toggle a tab's pinning in Chrome but couldn't find anything. Does anyone know one?

Comment: Related: [shortcut for accessing tab menu in Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/173364/shortcut-for-accessing-tab-menu-in-google-chrome?rq=1)

Comment: One more popular plugin with this feature is [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb).
You can pin/unpin tab with Alt+P

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After a little bit googling around, it seems there is none.

But you can select pin with P and unpin with U **at the right click of tab's context menu**.
Not handy at all.

Additionally, I found an extension named <strike>[URL Pinner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-pinner/lchefjdnocignejmkklgakfmnjhiimjh)</strike> with some useful features like auto pinning URL with regex matching, syncing settings etc.

**Edit:**

Apparently, the extension is gone from Chrome Web Store at least for now.

I'll try to curate some similar **alternatives** here:

- [Tab Pinner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-pinner/mcclikmfcmcpejkaobpfkmmbekbhedoi?hl=en-US)
  *(credit goes to [Brandon Søren Culley](https://superuser.com/users/253305/brandon-s%C3%B8ren-culley), he suggested this in the comments down below)*
- [Keyboard Shortcuts to Close Other/Right Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-clo/dkoadhojigekhckndaehenfbhcgfeepl) *(this is what I use for a while now and I'm very happy with it. Although it contains few more features and focuses than just pinning the tab, furthermore it can also handle pinning very well)*

**Untested alternatives**:

- [Pin Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-tab/dgldedkigbbalaioohedddpameekglma?hl=en)
- [Pin tabs - Tab Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-tabs-tab-manager/hhgfkccdcpjigagnmbfehocajjggifam?hl=en-US)

Comment: Great extension! It does so much more! You couldn't give a better answer.

Comment: The extension may be out of date for the latest versions of Chrome (version 67 as of this writing). It will fail to install due to an "Invalid manifest" error.

Comment: Looks like the extension is still working in chrome, here is the updated link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-pinner/mcclikmfcmcpejkaobpfkmmbekbhedoi?hl=en-US

Comment: I'm trying to keep the answer up to date as the extension is down on the store for a while now and it might be the first/popular reference regarding this topic. So please comment on the new alternatives and your experiences/thoughts about them in here if you find or try something like @BrandonSørenCulley did. This way I can curate them in the answer in an objective manner. Happy Pinning!

Answer (score 6):

Here is the one which works for me on Ubuntu Linux and Max OS X:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Note: Strangely it doesn't work on all websites eg. [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com).

**But there is a fix:** .

1. Install Chrome extension [*"Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)"*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck),
2. Open chrome settings,
3. Select extensions,
4. Find new extension: Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts),
5. Click on options and ["Custom Keyboard Shortcuts" Options page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDGdB.png)  will open,
6. Linux users: type your shortcut in *"Keyboard Shortcut"* field (eg. type: **alt+p**, **ctrl+p**),
7. MaxOS users type (eg. type: **option+p**, **control+p**, **command+p**) in the same field,
8. Select behavior Pin/unpin tab,
9. Click on *"Activation Settings..."* and check **"Active while in form fields"**,
10. Select **"All Websites"** in Website list,
11. Click Save and **RESTART** Chrome for changes to take effect.

Enjoy !

Comment: Do you know of a way to disable/change this shortcut? I'm on Ubuntu as well, and I want alt+p for something else.

Comment: Go to extensions and find shottkeys and click options then you'll see the entry which you added, you can change shortcut and remove it in needed. I don't see any disable option

Answer (score 5):

Add `Pin Tab` to [macOS System Preferences > Keyboards > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKB92.png) then map this to `⌘ + P` (or any key of your choice).

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me with control+P and option+P but setting it to command+shift+P did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Solid solution for Mac users that doesn't need installed software. "Pin Tab" is in the Tab menu. Option+P was no good but Cmd+P worked great.

Answer (score 4):

You can toggle tab pin using the pin/unpin commands in the [Ferro](http://www.getferro.com) extension, or by hitting the Alt-Shift-P keyboard shortcut (after installing Ferro).

Comment: to JacopKane: to unpin a tab via a shortcut, install Ferro. Assign a shortcut to "Pin a tab". On a pinned tab, hit this shortcut and your tab won't be pinned anymore. Thanks Friday for this awesome extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a super-lightweight solution which follows the [Unix philosophy of only doing one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). I can recommend the [pin tab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-tab/bghapojjfkdnhdcilgkaffabbfkbhhng?hl=en), it will give you the shortcut ALT+P to pin a tab.

Answer (score 0):

While @JacopKane's suggested extension should work for most use cases for Windows users, it does not register the macOS command key (I assume other keys as well).
[Tab Pinner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-pinner-keyboard-short/mbcjcnomlakhkechnbhmfjhnnllpbmlh) uses Chrome's native shortcut manager (I did not know this existed either). Go to the [extensions](http://chrome://extensions/) page, scroll down and click "Keyboard shortcuts". Now type in your preferred shortcut below the Tab Pinner section.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, without installing an extension is to do `cmd+shift+/` and type in `pin tab` to find it in the context menu.