# Hotkey to pin current tab in your browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, microsoft-edge

Or any other way of doing this via keyboard.

Browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Edge
OS'es: Ubuntu, Windows 10, Windows 11, OSX

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome (and so for Edge as well), various solutions are discussed
in the post
[What is the Google Chrome keyboard shortcut to pin/unpin a tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/533595/what-is-the-google-chrome-keyboard-shortcut-to-pin-unpin-a-tab)

For Firefox you will need an extension. Here are two examples
for adding the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>:

- [Toggle Pin Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toggle-pin-tab/)
- [Pin Unpin Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pinunpin-tab/)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, I'm using Microsoft Edge version `114.0.1823.82 (Official build) (64-bit)`, and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> keyboard shortcut toggles pinning the current working tab. I did not install any extension. I have not tried any other browsers.